# Dell XPS (late 2019) running ubuntu 20.04 Fan always on and very loud with kind of knocking sound that has started to give me headaches

Tags: 20.04, dell, fan

I have a Dell XPS that is about 13 months old now. It came with 18.04 but I have ran updates recently to update to 20.04.
Since about 1 month or so the fan seems to be always on (or starts very frequently). also the sound of the fan is extremely annoying with kind of a knocking sound that has started to give me headaches

I have searched a lot on what settings I can change to not start it so often, Power control seems to be set at Auto.

Any help would be highly appreciated. How do I debug it and how to fix it.
I cannot invest in another laptop for right now. I like everything else about the laptop.

Btw, I started noticing it only after the upgrades. but I think it was going on and off even before that as well.
Also I am running normal amount of application, like about 10 chrome tabs, vs code (max 2 windows). and slack (all the time) and just a few other simple apps. nothing overly complicated like games or 3d programs or drawing apps.

please help.

Comment: The fan has mechanical issues.

Comment: no way to fix ?

Comment: Back to Dell for new fan is the only think I know.

Answer (score 0):

TLDR: open the back-cover and  Clean the fans.

An update on this that I got so annoyed by the sound that I decided to open it up to clean. and I did just that, opened the back cover and with the laptop cleaning tools like the soft brush, carefully cleaned the fan with blowing on it to remove any stuck dust. when I opened it did not look that bad to be honest but the cleaning did improve it.
Now the fan is not Always on, it starts occasionally but even when it starts, there is no more the annoying knocking sound, it is just the whirring sound which is much better than before.